# derivation of the distance to the second of two vectors, easy example to understand

Tags: derivatives, vectors

Sorry for the easy question. I am trying to understand, through a simple example, why the partial derivative of the distance squared of two vectors returns this result:

[image]

Comment: Just write explicitly the derivative as a limit

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am honest to say that I did not get your hint, sorry.

Comment: I've added it explicitly as an answer. Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write explicitly the derivative, and note that $||\ ||^2=( )^2$. $$\frac{\partial J}{\partial q}=\lim_{\Delta q\to 0}\frac12\frac{(q+\Delta q-q_G)^2-(q-q_G)^2}{\Delta q}\\=\frac12\lim_{\Delta q\to 0}\frac{q^2+\Delta q^2+q_G^2+2q\Delta q-2qq_G-2q_G\Delta q-q^2-q_G^2+2qq_G}{\Delta q}$$